# Is it right that a rep recalc allowed me to claw back 1 rep that I'd spent down voting today?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-recalc

I'd like to bump this in order to find out if this is expected behaviour or not.  According to [comments posted by Grace Note and Michael Mrozek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/is-it-right-that-a-rep-recalc-allowed-me-to-claw-back-1-rep-that-id-spent-down#comment-174902), after I've submitted a down vote on an answer, up votes should restore the lost 1 point when I reach the rep cap.  However, this just isn't the case for me, only a recalc restores the lost 1 point.

Anyone can verify this by looking at [my reputation for today](https://stackoverflow.com/users/rep-day/94197/1321401600?sort=time&StartDate=2011-11-11).

---

#### Original post:

I hit my rep cap today, along with 2 accepted answers that would have taken my total to 230 if it weren't for a down vote I'd given a poor answer.  I was on 229 and continued to receive up votes that didn't count towards my score because of the cap.  Later, I was checking out the `/reputation` page and noticed the shiny new *'Trigger Reputation Recalc'* button, so I decided to press it.  When I revisited my summary page, I noticed that my daily reputation had gone up by 1 point, and this 1 point had been restored by one of the up votes that wasn't counted before the recalc:

[image]

You can see in the image that one of my answers has 6 up votes and 41 points.  I know that up votes are supposed to restore rep lost through down votes left on your posts, but they don't restore the reputation paid to down vote others.  Is this normal behaviour?  Could I spend all of my 30 votes down voting, then exceed the cap by 3 votes and restore my -30 with a rep recalc?

Comment: @Jeff: I guess it's not a bug then... isn't it a bug that up votes don't normally recover my -1s once I've reached the daily rep limit?

Answer (score 4):

It's perfectly reasonable.

I think you've hit an edge case for the "running total" rep calculation though. You should have got that 1 point from the 5th vote on the "What is the purpose of ...." question anyway.

Comment: Does that mean -1s *should* be restored by up votes after you've reached the rep limit?  Because they never are for me.

Comment: @Andy According to my reputation audit, mine have always been restored post-cap. And this isn't a recent change, as I had noticed this while researching a question from a few months back. So not quite sure why yours weren't reflected, but they always have been to my knowledge.

Comment: @Grace: weird.  It definitely wasn't restored until I performed the recalc - I had 229 for the day and I'd exceeded by several up votes.  -2s are always restored, but I've noticed that my -1s don't get restored.

Comment: IIRC a very long time ago you couldn't recover from downvotes, the cap was just permanently lowered for the day, but Grace Note is right that it's been the way it is now for quite a while